# Copy data from one workbook and paste into another workbook on to the next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple monthly files From January to December, each with the same template, containing data. I am looking to add a macro to each month that will transfer the data to an overall file that will contain all the information. I am hoping that the data from each month will paste into the overall file, adding to the previous data without removing the previous data. The data transferred should begin from the next empty row after the previous data.

Each month has a different amount of data so I have copied from the first row to the last row which can vary. I have then opened the file I wish to copy into. I have then, from what I believe, pasted into the the next empty row.

```
Private Sub()
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A9:EM" & Lastrow).Copy

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\US Div\FileName.xlsx"
    Worksheets("Premium Reporting").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Value = "Exported"
End Sub()
```

The data has been replacing the previous data and not adding to it.

Comment: looks straightforward. did you try recording the actions. hope that helps.

Comment: So is it copying and pasting?

Comment: you're positive column A has data in it at all times (copy location and paste location)?  you're finding the last row based on data in column A, so if the first cell in the last row is empty, you will overwrite